# How can I find the transfer function with Laplace in the (s) domain?

Tags: transfer-function, laplace-transform, function

How can I find the transfer function for this circuit with laplace in the (s) domain?

[image]

Comment: Re-write everything in s-domain (i.e. use \$sL\$ for inductors, \$1/(sC)\$ for capacitors, \$R\$ for resistors, \$V(s)\$ for input voltage, \$V_2(s)\$ for output voltage, \$I_3(s)\$ for the current flowing through 1F cap to the top) and find \$G(s) = V_2(s)/V(s)\$ using KVL & KCL.

Comment: Also give designators to each component like \$R_1, R_2, C_1, L_1\text{ etc.}\$. Have you heard of the superposition theorem? Please show input port and output port more clearly. Where have you got to? Where are you stuck?

Comment: U(t)—enter UL(t)—exit                          U(t)—enter. I3(t)—exit

Comment: In the middle of the circuit I see three components forming a star. I recommend to apply the star-triangle transformation. This simplifies the analysis.

Answer (score 3):

This 4th-order circuit - there are 4 energy-storing elements with independent state variables - can be solved using different approaches but I will use the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as I described them in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1960405195). The principle at work is to determine the time constants by finding the resistance \$R\$ that drives a given capacitor or an inductor while the other elements are set in their dc- or high-frequency state. With \$R\$ in hand, you can then write the corresponding time constant as \$\tau=RC\$ when it involves a capacitor or \$\tau=\frac{L}{R}\$ with an inductor.

If we start with the denominator \$D(s)\$, we will turn the excitation off (the voltage source \$V_{in}\$ is replaced by a short circuit and we "look" through each energy-storing component's connecting port to determine what resistance \$R\$ it offers. There are plenty of combinations considering the order of the circuit but the flow is detailed in my documents:

[image]

As you can see, no equation, just what is called *inspection*: determine, in your head, what the resistance \$R\$ is. If you draw carefully and organize your drawings properly, it is a fairly fluid process. When you have determined all the time constants in this mode, assemble them to form the denominator \$D(s) = 1+b_1s+b_2s^2+b_3s^3+b_4s^4\$.

For the zeros, instead of determining time constants, I will alternatively set each element in its high-frequency state (a short circuit for a capacitor and an open-circuit for an inductor) then determine the gain in these configurations. Again, just inspect the circuit, the gain will often be zero considering \$L_4\$ shorting the output in dc:

[image]

Then combine these gains with the already-found time constants and you have this nice Mathcad sheet:

[image]

The final transfer function is shown below with its Thévenin equivalent circuit that I did not dare to expand:

[image]

I will then plot these two expressions and check if I spot any deviation between the two. I usually subtract magnitude and phase and the result should be in the pico range, which is the resolution of the solver. Any deviation indicates an error in one of the small sketches: it is then convenient to review the drawings and identify the guilty one(s): just update the time constant and there you go, correction is done, no need to re-start from scratch:

[image]

The two expressions are rigorously identical and lead to the same magnitude/phase plots. The next step would then be to factor the denominator in two second-order polynomials and unveil resonant frequencies and quality factors. This is what you would need for designing this filter (design-oriented analysis or D-OA). Same goes for the numerator which can tentatively be rearranged by comparing the various coefficients but I will stop here for now.